# Suffix Aliases feature in powershell

Tags: powershell, alias

I'm looking for ability to run certain cmdlets when calling files with some extensions. For example, when calling `PS> .\test.php` I want to call `Invoke-Php .\test.php`. Something like [suffix aliases](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/aliassuffix) in ZSH.

For now I know that i can just assign php extension to some script, but it will affect explorer too, and it's not what i'm looking for. Maybe it's possible to "hook" expression invoking process?

Edit:
I'm looking for something like that: https://serverfault.com/questions/165598/can-i-hook-powershell-to-call-a-function-each-time-i-execute-a-command/186468#186468 but working not only in PATH.